# Multiplying specific observations in dataframe with different values

Tags: r, dplyr

I currently have a df in R with the following format:

```
   Observation  Count
    PSEMEN  289
    PSEMEN  289
    PSEMEN  289
    ABIPRO  18
    ABIPRO  18
    PSEMEN  289
    PSEMEN  289
    TSUMER  195
    TSUHET  1
    ABIPRO  18
```

I need to create a new column named Value and multiply specific observations (i.e TSUHET and ABIPRO) by 70% and everything else by 30%. I am not really sure how to go about executing this but the approach I was thinking of was something along the lines of:

```
mutate(Value = If TSUHET OR ABIPRO then * .70 
else everything else *.30)
```

Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if_else` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Value = Count * if_else(Observation %in% c('TSUHET', 'ABIPRO'), 0.7, 0.3)) 

#   Observation Count Value
#1       PSEMEN   289  86.7
#2       PSEMEN   289  86.7
#3       PSEMEN   289  86.7
#4       ABIPRO    18  12.6
#5       ABIPRO    18  12.6
#6       PSEMEN   289  86.7
#7       PSEMEN   289  86.7
#8       TSUMER   195  58.5
#9       TSUHET     1   0.7
#10      ABIPRO    18  12.6
```

Or in base R :

```
transform(df,Value = Count * ifelse(Observation %in% c('TSUHET', 'ABIPRO'), 0.7, 0.3))
```

---

If you'll have multiple values to compare then you can use `case_when` which is clearer

```
df %>%
  mutate(Value = Count * case_when(Observation %in% c('TSUHET', 'ABIPRO')~0.7, 
                                   Observation == 'PINMON' ~0.1, 
                                   TRUE ~ 0.3))
```

Comment: If in the future I add another observation, lets say PINMON and I want those multiplied by something else (.10), can I add another ifelse right after c('TSUHET', 'ABIPRO'), and add the count * .10 in between the 0.7 and 0.3?

Comment: Yes, you can do that or better is to use `case_when` which is an alternative to nested ifelse commands. See updated answer.